# Paragraph Alignment Issue

Tags: html, css

I want this "Role" paragraph to be aligned to the bottom of "copy" div..as well should expand with the content.
[Here is the link](http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/projects.html)

Comment: Please post a representative sample of code.

Comment: what do you mean 'aligned to the bottom of "copy" div? aligned in what way?  Vertical, horizontal,  spiritual?

Comment: I want it aligned Vertically bottom

Comment: If I remove that, the line (border-bottom: 1px solid #9d9d9d;) of description won't match/ align with the secondrary column ( screenshot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems too easy, but remove the rule `height: 237px` from `.project .description`.

It then looks like this:

[image]

Comment: If I remove that, the line (border-bottom: 1px solid #9d9d9d;) of description won't match/ align with the secondrary column ( screenshot)

Comment: You haven't thought this through well enough. The quickest way to make it work now is this: Remove the height, as per my answer. Remove the `border-bottom` on both `.project .description` and `.project .thumb`. Add a background image to `.project` with this CSS: `background: url(borderImage.png) left bottom no-repeat`. You'll have to make `borderImage.png` - it should be a `1px` high image, which contains the two "border lines", [like this](http://i.imgur.com/ID37w.png), but precise. Other ways to achieve this will require significant changes.

Comment: if I add the borders as image, how will it do as the page increases/ decreases by width?

Comment: Your current page doesn't increase/decrease by width. Are you going to change it to do so?

Comment: @thirtydot -- when you say significant changes, what would be that?? Just want to know the other ways to do..My other pages scale with the browsers..after you said I realized that this page is not..When I increase my browser size, the images are floating outside.

Comment: By "significant changes", I mean that you'll probably need a multitude of different tweaks to get the page how you want it. Stick the version with working fluid width live, and I'll take another look..

Comment: @thiyrtdot -- how did you do that image with space in between??

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I opened Paint, drew a line, drew another line, saved the file. It was just an example image.

Comment: @thirtydot -- I tried to do with photoshop..I felt its more complicated..I'll try with paint

Comment: @thirtydot -- I changed the width to fluid. It works now. http://dragonfly.zymichost.com/projects.html. I appreciate your suggestions/ inputs for further modification. Thanks

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I do have one suggestion: change the `min-width` on `#container` to `880px`, to stop your images dropping down when the window is narrow.